# Multiple emails from PHP application using Gmail SMTP

Tags: email, cakephp, asynchronous, smtp

I am working on an application which need to notify around 100 people at once when a **specific** condition is met. Now when a user who is performing the action which results in the **specific** condition need to wait till all 100 emails are sent which takes quite long using Gmail SMTP. The application is built on top of Cake PHP.

My question is whether there is a way application can send 100 emails without blocking the user whose action results in meeting the **specific** condition.

To make my question clear, think of Groupon. It sends notification to all buyers when minimum numbers of buyers are met. So when the nth person make the purchase, Google sends the notification.One way is to notify all buyers immediately after the purchase is complete (which is what we are doing n context of our application) and probably other way is to wait and send the notification using an external script/app at a pre-defined time.

In case of former, the application would block while sending emails is complete. Since PHP deosn't support multi-threading, I was wondering if there is an easy way to make this operation asynchoronous so it doesn't affect main application flow.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the notification in a queue, and use a cronjob that checks and sends notifications every 5 minutes. That way your user isn't locked up while the operation happens.

I'm not 100% sure, but you might be able to use an ajax call too, which would keep the user free to carry on after the request is sent.